# Is it possible to generate both an FMT and a table from a CSV file?

Tags: sql-server, bcp

So I need a way to import CSVs that vary in column names, column order, and number of columns. They will always be CSV and of course comma-delimited.

Is it possible to generate both FMT and a temp table creation script of a CSV file?

From what I can gather, you need one or the other. For example, you need the table to generate the FMT file using the bcp utility. And you need the FMT file to dynamically build a create script for a table.

Comment: Are you saying that csv files will be coming at you with unexpected or "unannounced" layouts/formats? Or just that you have many different CSV's to load, but you get info on their layout/formats ahead of time so you can prepare? Are you looking to dynamically inspect a CSV and create a fmt file and table to load into? Or will you be able to create these ahead of time?

Comment: But yes, this can be done, but the answer depends on what your exact situation is.

Comment: yes to the first question, they will have unexpected layouts, and i want to dynamically create both to load them.

Comment: I do not get information about their layouts ahead of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using just SQL and to dynamically load files text files there is no quick way to do this. I see one option:

1. Get the data into SQL Server as a single column (bcp it in or use
   t-sql and openrowset to load, SSIS, etc...). Be sure to include in this table a second column that is an identity (I'll call it "row_nbr"). You will need this to find the first row to get column names from the header in the file.
2. Parse the first record "where row_nbr = 1" to get the header record. You will need a string parse function (find online, or create your own) to substring out each column name.
3. Build dynamic SQL statement to create a new table with the parsed
   out number of fields you just found. Must calculate lengths and use
   a generic "varchar" data type since you wont know how to type the
   data. Use column names found above.
4. Once you have a table created with the correct number of adequately 
   sized columns, you can create the format file.

I assumed, in my answer, that you are comfortable with doing all these things, just shared the logical flow at a high level. I can add more if you need more detail.

Comment: I'll add... if the file includes headers, that would be a big help. If so, then you just use the first line loaded from the file in your table where you've loaded the entire line into a single column... use that line to get column names... at least, hopefully.

Comment: it does include column headers

Comment: i'm building a way so that users can "map" columns in my system to columns provided via the csv. Some columns with numerical values will have more than 1 associated csv column, and these values will need to be added up. It's a bit tough to explain but, in essence i need the data dump in a temp or droppable table.

Comment: Updated. whatchya think?

Comment: Awesome. I would also suggest a change to the title. Maybe "dynamically load csv files with unknown, varying layouts"? Good luck!